# Python how i can divide multiply count of numbers

Tags: python

I have some code like

```
if any(i < 0.7 for i in [
        len(element_1) / len(element_2),
        len(element_3) / len(element_4),
        ]):
```

But i need divide unknown number of items for example,

```
if any(i < 0.7 for i in [
        len(element_1) / len(element_2),
        len(element_3) / len(element_4),
        len(element_5) / len(element_6),
        len(element_7) / len(element_8),
        ]):
```

How i can do it? Will be grateful for the help

Comment: Are your `element_` in a list? If not, why not?

Comment: @khelwood My element in set i need get % unique items

Comment: @MrOldSir But a set's unordered... I'm confused. Please [edit] the question to include the definition(s). See [mre] for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
if any(len(a) / len(b) < 0.7 for a, b in zip(elements[::2], elements[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply (with one-step shifting):

```
if any(len(elements[i]) / len(elements[i+1]) < 0.7 
       for i in range(0, len(elements), 2)):
    ...
```